# Getting the result of a CompletableFuture.supplyAsync

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, completable-future, nhlambdaextensions

I have this piece of code:

```
CompletableFuture
    .supplyAsync(() -> {
        return  smsService.sendSMS(number);
    }).thenApply(result -> {
        LOG.info("SMS sended " + result);
    });
```

but I got a compilation error:

> The method `thenApply(Function<? super Boolean,? extends U>)` in the type
>   `CompletableFuture<Boolean>` is not applicable for the arguments `((<no type> result) -> {})`

Comment: I do not hve the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `thenAccept` not `thenApply`

`thenApply` takes a `Function` which is of the form

```
public interface Function<T, R> {
    R apply(T t);
}
```

`thenAccept` takes a `Consumer` which is of the form

```
public interface Consumer<T> {
    void accept(T t);
}
```

The lambda you provided does not have a return value; it is void. Because a generic type parameter cannot be void your lambda cannot be casted as a `Function` interface. On the other hand, the `Consumer` has a void return type which the lambda could satisfy.